# Unable to run for loop on table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm iterating through a table of data, and when it runs, it prints the data as blank (" "), and when I change the syntax, it doesn't work at all.  Hopefully this code is enough to understand why these issues are occurring.  Any ideas?

```
rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-table"]/tbody[1]/tr')) # count number of rows

columns = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-table"]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td')) # count num of columns

print(rows)
print(columns)

for r in range(0,rows+1):
    for c in range(1,columns+1):
        value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rod-table']/tbody[1]/tr[" + str(r) + "]/td[" + str(c) + "]").text
        print(value)
    print()
```

Comment: my guess is, that the tag has really no text contents like for example `<p> </p>`
for the html item "<h1>hello</h1>"  element.text() would be `hello`
Alternatively perhaps you do not get the element that you'd expect to get or you try to get the text before the javascript, that is populating it had time to be executed.
DIfficult to say without more context

Comment: Show a real example, or the url, and the desired output in order to get proper help.